# How do CRMs connect to Email accounts to interact with them? (i.e. Gmail)?

Tags: crm, email

This is not a code question but more of a process question. I've had a few people ask me about CRMs and the way they connect to email.  I'm not sure about how they do this. When I write web or iOS applications I can send email via API or SMTP but I'm not sure how to really make a CRM "interact" with an email account.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

I know about - Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

It has its own Email router/Server side sync (Exchange) to deliver & receive email through Queue concept.

Even the most powerful Outlook client helps to integrate with CRM from your workplace :)

(These are just pointers, pls explore yourself with these keywords in google)

Comment: thanks.... I'm starting with building a PHP/Python app and want to being in Email Support.